# Use a QObject that might be deleted in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++20, qt6

I have a QObject `child` that is part of a hierarchy with the root `root`. In a concurrent application without parallelism, I can use QPointer to ensure that `child` still exists.

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPointer>
#include <future>

struct Child: QObject {
    using QObject::QObject;
    ~Child() { qDebug() << "delete child!"; }
};

int main() {
    auto const root = new QObject;
    auto const child = new Child(root);

    auto work = std::async(std::launch::deferred,
        [child = QPointer(child)]{
            if(child) {
                qDebug() << "child exists";
            } else {
                qDebug() << "child was deleted";
            }
        });

    delete root;

    work.get();
}
```

```
delete child!
child was deleted
```

This works perfectly well, since everything is executed in the same thread.

If I replace `launch::deferred` with `launch::async`, a new thread is created for execution. `QPointer` then does not work anymore, the output is (almost always):

```
delete child!
child exists
```

Of course I could not use `QPointer` for this purpose anyway, because with parallel execution the deletion could take place after the `if`.

What I would need is a `QSharedPointer` in the object hierarchy of `root`. Then I could give a `QWeakPointer` to the worker thread and lock it in the worker function, i.e. temporarily convert it into a `QSharedPointer`.

Is there any way to implement this approach or is there perhaps another way to use `child` thread-safe?

---

The comments have shown me that I may have asked the wrong question. What I want is to load data from the `child` object in the worker function if it still exists. This data is processed in the worker, which takes a few seconds. The result must be passed back to the `child` object. It is important that after the retrieval of the data also compellingly the set must take place again!

The `QObject`s are derived from `QWidget` in my case.

Can this be realized or do I have to separate this data part more from the GUI?

The whole thing looks something like this:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QPointer>
#include <future>

struct Root: QObject {
    using QObject::QObject;
    ~Root() {qDebug() << "delete root!"; }
};

struct Child: QObject {
    using QObject::QObject;
    ~Child() {qDebug() << "delete child!"; }
    QString getSource() { qDebug() << "get"; return data; }
    void setTarget(QString target) { qDebug() << "set" << target; }
    QString data = "data";
};

int main() {
    auto const root = new Root;
    auto const child = new Child(root);

    auto work = std::async(std::launch::async,
        [child]{
            auto data = child->getSource();
            // process data
            child->setTarget(data);
        });

    delete root;

    work.get();
}
```

Comment: I think if you want to go the QSharedPointer route, you cannot also use QObject's built-in parent-child auto-delete. You would have to release the child's memory differently.

Comment: @JarMan Is there a way to prevent the object hierarchy from deleting `child` if it is part of it?

Comment: Don't add it to the parent so the parent will not delete it.

Comment: It's actually a widget, I can't not so this :-/

Comment: If it's actually a widget then it can't be directly accessed from any thread other than that on which `main` is running -- so the whole issue is moot, right?

Comment: @G.M. Why not? There some actions that are only allowed inside the GUI thread, but apart from these its a normal C++ class, isn't it? However, sending the data via the signal slot mechanism might be a workable solution for my case. This works across thread boundaries if I remember correctly.

Comment: QObjects are not really thread safe. Obviously you can add your own thread safe methods. But as a rule of thumb, do not use QObjects between threads. Do whatever you want to do in some other way.

Comment: *"its a normal C++ class, isn't it?"*, not really. It has thread affinity and parent (which also has thread affinity etc) and the class has associated metaobject. Of course this all is C++ code, so in that sense it is "normal", bit otherwise not.

Comment: @hyde Okay, looks like I need to learn more about how Qt does work. I updated the question to be more specific about my actual issue. Thanks to all commenters so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle multithreading properly I suggest you use signals and slots. Qt already includes an excellent support for multithreading and signals and slots handle multithreading very well. This example may be useful, but there are many others: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcore-threads-queuedcustomtype-example.html.

Refer to this to learn more: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/threads.html.

To stick to the example you provided, it could be simple to just store the reference to your child in a pointer somewhere and share it between the two threads, by using an appropriate QMutex. Set it in the ctor inside the mutex, reset to nullptr in the dtor inside a QMutex. Always use it under QMutex. But I do not like this approach at all.